# Compare chi-squared goodness of fit results for Poisson and Negative binomial

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, poisson-distribution, goodness-of-fit, negative-binomial-distribution

Steps followed for testing :

1. Derive parameter estimates using `fitdistr()` function in `MASS` package for the dataset, dt consisting of discrete values varying from 0 to 50.

```
df=dt[[1]]
nbfit <- fitdistr(df,'negative binomial')
pfit <- fitdist(df, "pois")
```

2. Use parameter estimates for creating reference distribution

```
    fitnb <- dnbinom(0:50, size=0.4, mu=3.9)
    fitp <- dpois(0:50, lambda=3.9)
```

I found that `lambda` value is same as `mu`.

3. Get frequencies

```
    t <- table(df)   
    D <- as.data.frame(t)
    observed_freq <- D$Freq
```

4. perform the chi-squared test

```
chisq.test(observed_freq, fitnb, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
chisq.test(observed_freq, fitp , simulate.p.value = TRUE)
```

5. Results

for NB

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  observed_freq and fitnb
X-squared = 476, df = NA, p-value = 0.989
```

for Poisson

```
    Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  observed_freq and fitp
X-squared = 476, df = NA, p-value = 0.9875
```

Question:

1. What can we comment upon which distribution fits better? Clearly, for both X-squared is the same and we fail to reject the null hypothesis.
2. Can I perform some other test?

******Edit******

I also used lrtest() function and got the following result:

```
fit_poi <- fitdistr(df,"poisson")
fit_nbin <- fitdistr(df,"negative binomial")
lrtest(fit_poi,fit_nbin)
```

Result

```
Model 1: fit_poi
Model 2: fit_nbin
  #Df  LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)    
1   1 -2537.7                         
2   2 -1159.3  1 2756.6  < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

With this, can we say negative binomial performs better?

Histogram of actual data used in the test (Note: Codes differ a little based on this dataset)

[image]

**Actual data**

```
value   count
0   205
1   65
2   40
3   40
4   32
5   18
6   15
7   11
8   8
9   9
10  7
11  6
12  8
13  3
14  1
15  8
16  2
18  2
19  2
20  5
21  1
23  2
24  1
25  1
29  1
31  1
32  2
35  1
36  1
42  1
43  1
45  1
50  1
53  1
```

Comment: The null is not rejected.

Comment: You can apply a likelihood ratio test because the models are nested.

Comment: @utobi for applying lrtest I fist need to build models. How to do that? What is X and Y?

Comment: Note that `ppois(50-1, 3.9, lower.tail = FALSE)` returns `2.5757e-37`. I find it suspicious when a value so extreme (50) that it (or any larger one) should occur with a chance less than $10^{-36}$ arises in a sample of 2000: that's an astronomically rare event.  Not knowing anything about the dataset, I am thereby inclined to mistrust all these results.  What have you done to verify that these analyses make sense and give decent descriptions of your data?

Comment: @utobi can you give any suggestion regarding the results obtained from lrtest. Please see the edits section

Comment: I don't believe the lrtest results either, because you reported identical chi-squared statistics for the two models (rounded to an integer). The LR test result depends directly on the difference of those statistics which, being essentially zero, indicates there's no significant improvement in the NB model.  Something is very fishy here.

Comment: @vp_050, unfortunately, the usual LR test cannot be applied here because the null implies a parameter value on its border. As I said, I'm elaborating on this and I'm writing an answer.

Comment: @whuber I have posted a histogram of the actual dataset. There are 503 points in total. Can this be helpful?

Comment: I looked at the data.   *They aren't remotely like a Poisson distribution of any parameter.*  One way to tell is that you have a definite mode at $1,$ no values of $0,$ a mean of $3.77888,$ and a long string of values out to $50.$  The Poisson distribution with the same mean would have around 11 zeros, a mode at 4, and no values beyond 12 or so.

Comment: @whuber But there are zeros: value count
0 205
1 65
2 40
3 40
4 32
5 18
6 15
7 11
8 8
9 9
10 7
11 6
12 8
13 3
14 1
15 8
16 2
18 2
19 2
20 5
21 1
23 2
24 1
25 1
29 1
31 1
32 2
35 1
36 1
42 1
43 1
45 1
50 1
53 1

Comment: Thank you for posting that: I was off by 1 in reading your plot.  Even so, this is even *more* non-Poisson.  You are not using the chi-squared test correctly, but it looks like you're getting the right likelihoods in your LR test.  What you need to do is compare the negative binomial fit to the data to see whether it's reasonable.  (It is.)

Comment: @whuber In chisq.test(observed_freq, fitnb, simulate.p.value = TRUE)
observed freq is from actual dataset and expected proportions are from fitnb model. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: In several ways.  One is that you have *zero* observed frequencies of many values, such as 26, 27, 28, 30, 33, *etc.*  Indeed, I'm surprised `chisq.test` accepts `fitnb` as an argument.  I believe it's returning nonsense but gives you no warning.

Comment: @whuber I had actually run the following code in my original script fitnb <- dnbinom(c(0:16, 18:21, 23:25, 29,31,32,35,36, 42, 43,45, 50,53), size=0.4, mu=3.9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**About 1.** Your chi-squared test does not reject $H_0$, thus the two fits are statistically equivalent; By [Occam's Razor principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) the Poisson model, i.e. the most parsimonious of the two, is to be preferred. However, as noted in the comments by whuber, these tests seem to give strange results; see the **Addendum** below.

**About 2.** The test you are looking for is sometimes called a test for overdispersion since the Poisson distribution imposes the "mean equals variance" assumption. Since the Poisson distribution is a particular case of the Negative Binomial distribution when the latter is expressed in a particular parametrization, then a likelihood ratio test can be applied. However, this test doesn't have the usual $\chi^2$ limiting distribution due to the fact that the parameter being tested is assumed on the border of the parameter space.

The easiest solution is then to apply a score test (Dean and Lawless, 1989 "Tests for detecting overdispersion in Poisson
regression models", *Journal of the American Statistical Association* **84**: 467–472.). This amounts to applying a $t$-test to

$$
Z_i = \frac{(Y_i - \mu_i)^2 - \mu_i}{\mu_i\sqrt{2}}.
$$

The test is *post-hoc*, in the sense that it is performed subsequent to modelling the data.

Here is an `R` example applied to a simulated variable from the Poisson distribution.

```
# generate some data
set.seed(12)
x <- data.frame(y = rpois(30,3.5))

fit_poi <- glm(y~1, family = "poisson", data = x)
mu <- predict(fit_poi, type="response")
z <- ((x$y - mu)**2 - x$y)/ (mu * sqrt(2))
zscore <- lm(z ~ 1)
summary(zscore)

Call:
lm(formula = z ~ 1)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.67076 -0.55149 -0.27887  0.07895  2.87330 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.08207    0.16413    -0.5    0.621

Residual standard error: 0.899 on 29 degrees of freedom
```

The p-value is $0.621$ thus we cannot reject the null hypothesis and conclude that the data are not overdispersed.

**Addendum**

With your data the score test gives:

```
summary(zscore)
Call:
lm(formula = z ~ 1)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
 -9.19  -8.19  -5.72  -5.72 422.01 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)    8.463      1.660   5.099 4.85e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 37.22 on 502 degrees of freedom
```

The conclusion is that the data are definitely overdispersed, so non-Poisson. You should then opt for the Negative Binomial and as suspected above (and by whuber in the comments to your post) there must be something wrong with your first chi-squared test.

Comment: This worked. I got the same result. Thanks.